# Registering SMS notification on iPhone

Tags: iphone, notifications, sms

Is there a way to implement a method that will notify the app that sms is receivec and then do something, in example turn on the LED light?

Answer (score 1):

No. Apple would consider this a privacy violation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API that provides access to SMS messages, for privacy reasons.